# Apache Error - child process [xxx] still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM & ServerContext: 1 leaked_rewrite_drivers on destruction

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-pagespeed

I have many error log entries called

```
 ServerContext: 1 leaked_rewrite_drivers on destruction
```

AND

```
child process 10494 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
```

does anyone has any idea on how to fix these errors ?

Comment: According to thin link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mod-pagespeed-discuss/EdJ-Zq9Kl50 : mod_pagespeed optimizes resources in the background in response to HTML requests.  After the HTML request is completed, there can still be optimization work going on.  If Apache decides to shut down the child process, then mod_pagespeed attempts to delay the shutdown for about 1 second before giving up and shutting down anyway (issuing the message you get).

Answer (score 0):

Issue regarding child process does not stop... and in case many child make same case it going to KILL and Stop Apache2.

I found same concern with Apache2 with proxy.

On my cloud server have huge traffic and lot customer instance so same issue whole week I monitor and found,

## connectiontimeout=150 timeout=600  #SnippetBucket.com

This causes big issues.

than newly optimized values I set

## connectiontimeout=10 timeout=20   #SnippetBucket.com

I got issue resolved, I able to resolve only after 7 days of dedicated monitoring on server.